# Why I'm getting "Dynamic SOQL :System.QueryException: unexpected token:SelectId" Error at the time of debugging

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, unexpectedexception

getting unexpected token error as in image when I debug and pass parameters to this class as below

```apex
public class SearchObj {
    public static void searchRecord(String strObjectName,String strFieldName)
    {
        String strQuery='Select'+strFieldName +'from'+strObjectName;
        system.debug(strQuery);
        
        List<sObject> lstDetails=database.query(strQuery);
        for (sObject objRec:lstDetails)
        {
            system.debug(objRec.get('Name'));
             system.debug(objRec.get('BillingCity'));
             system.debug(objRec.get('Industry'));
        }
    }    
}
```

Below in anonymous window

```
SearchObj.searchRecord('Account', 'Name,BillingCity,Industry');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give space after SELECT and FROM

```
String strQuery='Select '+strFieldName +' from '+strObjectName
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for help. I tried with spaces and entered as SearchObj.searchRecord('Account', 'Name,BillingCity,Industry'); in anonymous window. now getting same error with <EOF>(in place of 'SelectName')

Comment: can you show what you are trying?

Comment: Make sure you are adding ; at the end while calling from anonymous.Also space should be there before and after FROM. See my answer.

Comment: ..Thankyou again ..yeah its working now !! was missing space before FROM.

Answer (score 1):

Your SOQL is malformed. You need spaces between each token. As written, your generated SOQL looks like:

```
SELECTNameFROMAccount
```

Try:

```
String strQuery = String.format(
  'SELECT {0} FROM {1}', 
  new String[] {
    strFieldName, 
    strObjectName 
  }
);
```

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Without knowing more, it's hard to say, but you might be looking for SOSL, instead.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your quick reply. Actually, I want to create a function for record search in object where I can pass Object Name,  Field Name(List) as parameter